# SPO Settings Options

Tags: site, site-settings, settings, spo

I have a SPO site created in our tenant that shows up all the options under the settings gear like Add a page, Add a App, site permissions etc. (8 options in total). We migrated a site collection from SP 2010 to SPO using ShareGate. Once migrated, when we navigated to Settings, I see only 5 options. I do not see the Site permissions, Add a page or Add a App like below. I am the SCA for the migrated site and also part of the owners group.

[image]

Any idea about this?

Regards
Vj

Answer (score 1):

In general, if you've migrated to a Classic Team site (STS#0) you will see this list of options. Modern Team sites (STS#3) will have additional options.

For classic Team sites, the options will be in Site Settings, much like they are for your on-prem SharePoint.

You will also see this dialog for any page (List, Library, etc.) that is presented in a classic view. If you switch to a modern view of those objects, you'll see the expanded options.

Comment: So, if I want the migrated site to be classic site, how do I get to the site permissions page which I dont see here?

Comment: You should be able to access site permissions page with the standard url: https://{yoursiteurl}/_layouts/15/user.aspx even if the link is not visible on the site settings page